# Methods aren't working as expected within the code - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal:
Apply this new js file (displayModalContent.js)  with code and the application should be enabled to use without any error. (from stackblitz after or after)

Problem:
I cannot make it to be working with the new js file after doing refactoring. The modal don't display. What part am I missing?

Stackblitz Before:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8schc7?

Stackblitz After:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-kcwy7a?

---

Before:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 'Jan' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Feb' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Mars' },
  { value: 4, label: 'April' },
  { value: 5, label: 'May' },
  { value: 6, label: 'June' },
  { value: 7, label: 'July' },
  { value: 8, label: 'August' },
  { value: 9, label: 'Sept' },
  { value: 10, label: 'Oct' },
  { value: 11, label: 'Nov' },
  { value: 12, label: 'Dec' }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      items: [
        {
          firstName: 'Josef',
          lastName: 'Anderson',
          key: 'josef.anderson',
          startYear: 2021,
          startMonth: 2
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Jim',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'jim.west',
          startYear: 2020,
          startMonth: 3
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Joe',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'joe.west',
          startYear: 1998,
          startMonth: 10
        }
      ],
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map(item => {
              const { firstName, lastName, key } = item;

              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{firstName}</td>
                  <td>{lastName}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(item)}>
                      Open Modal
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div>
          {openItem !== null && (
            <Modal className="confirmation-modal" isOpen={true}>
              First Name:
              <br />
              <input
                type="text"
                id="firstName"
                name="firstName"
                value={openItem.firstName}
                onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
              />
              <input
                type="text"
                id="lastName"
                name="lastName"
                value={openItem.lastName}
                onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
              />
              <Select
                defaultValue={options.find(
                  option => option.value === openItem.startMonth
                )}
                name="startMonth"
                id="testaaa"
                options={options}
              />
              <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Test</button>
            </Modal>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Modal.setAppElement(document.getElementById('root'));
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

```
h1,
p {
  font-family: Lato;
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.confirmation-overlay.ReactModal__Overlay--after-open {
  opacity: 1;

  transition: opacity 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content {
  position: absolute;

  top: 25%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 500px;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: scale(0);
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  outline: none;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.confirmation-modal.ReactModal__Content--after-open {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  transition: all 300ms ease-out;
}

.confirmation-modal button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  padding: 4px 8px;
  margin: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.confirmation-modal button:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

---

After:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';
import DisplayModalContent from './displayModalContent';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      items: [
        {
          firstName: 'Josef',
          lastName: 'Anderson',
          key: 'josef.anderson',
          startYear: 2021,
          startMonth: 2
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Jim',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'jim.west',
          startYear: 2020,
          startMonth: 3
        },
        {
          firstName: 'Joe',
          lastName: 'West',
          key: 'joe.west',
          startYear: 1998,
          startMonth: 10
        }
      ],
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <table border="1">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>First Name</th>
              <th>Last Name</th>
              <th />
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {items.map(item => {
              const { firstName, lastName, key } = item;

              return (
                <tr key={key}>
                  <td>{firstName}</td>
                  <td>{lastName}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button onClick={() => this.handleOpenModal(item)}>
                      Open Modal
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <DisplayModalContent item={openItem} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Modal.setAppElement(document.getElementById('root'));
render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

---

After (displayModalContent.js):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 1, label: 'Jan' },
  { value: 2, label: 'Feb' },
  { value: 3, label: 'Mars' },
  { value: 4, label: 'April' },
  { value: 5, label: 'May' },
  { value: 6, label: 'June' },
  { value: 7, label: 'July' },
  { value: 8, label: 'August' },
  { value: 9, label: 'Sept' },
  { value: 10, label: 'Oct' },
  { value: 11, label: 'Nov' },
  { value: 12, label: 'Dec' }
];

class displayModalContent extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      openItem: null,
      firstName: '',
      lastName: ''
    };
  }

  handleOpenModal = openItem => {
    this.setState({ openItem });
  };

  handleCloseModal = () => {
    this.setState({ openItem: null });
  };

  handleOpenItemValue = e => {
    let { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      openItem: { ...this.state.openItem, [name]: value }
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value);
    alert(
      JSON.stringify({
        test: document.getElementsByName('startMonth')[0].value
      })
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { items, openItem } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {openItem !== null && (
          <Modal className="confirmation-modal" isOpen={true}>
            First Name:
            <br />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="firstName"
              name="firstName"
              value={openItem.firstName}
              onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
            />
            <input
              type="text"
              id="lastName"
              name="lastName"
              value={openItem.lastName}
              onChange={e => this.handleOpenItemValue(e)}
            />
            <Select
              defaultValue={options.find(
                option => option.value === openItem.startMonth
              )}
              name="startMonth"
              id="testaaa"
              options={options}
            />
            <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Test</button>
          </Modal>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default displayModalContent;
```

Comment: Please add some relevant code here.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question and provide more details about what the issue or your question is, any debugging you've tried, and actual vs. expected results.

Comment: 'Please add some relevant code here.' added code

Comment: 'Please include a Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example in your question and provide more details about what the issue or your question is, any debugging you've tried, and actual vs. expected result' Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a lifecycle method in order to populate openItem in displayModalContent.js file

```
  componentDidUpdate(s, p) {
    if (JSON.stringify(this.props) !== JSON.stringify(s)) {
      this.setState({ openItem: this.props.item });
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works.  (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-569cus?). Thank you